# Using Torch for Time Series prediction using LSTMs

Tags: numpy, neural-network, torch, pybrain, lstm

My main problem is how should I pre-process my dataset that is basically a 60 minutely sequenced numbers inputs that will result in a 1 hourly output. Knowing that each input vector every minute is producing some output, but unfortunately this output can't be observed until 1 hour is passed.

I thought about considering putting 60 inputs as one big input vector which corresponds to 1 hourly output on a normal ML classfier, hence having 1 sample at a time. But I don't think it would be time series anymore.

How can I represent that to be doable in an LSTM environment?